# A rebus puzzle describing a name

Tags: knowledge, rebus, computer-puzzle

This is a rebus puzzle describing a singer's name. This puzzle will still be pretty straight-forward, though you really need a little knowledge in programming this time...

```
import math

a = name['>_']
b = name['&']
c = name[(-1)**.5]
d = name[sum(1 / math.factorial(i) for i in range(20))]
e = name['8848m']
f = name['android']
assert [len(i) for i in (a, b, c, d, e, f)] == [7, 3, 1, 1, 16, 5]
answer = '{}{}{}{}\x20{}{}'.format(a[::3], b[1], c, d, e.split()[0].replace('lest', ''), f[2::])
```

The answer is the hypothetical value of the variable `answer` of the Python program above.

But you don't have to run the code at all. Un fact you can't run it. The first line will raise `NameError`, because `name` is not defined. That is the whole point of this puzzle: you need to guess what the `name` dictionary contains. Its values are all `str`s. I updated the code so you can actually get the keys. The values are simple English words/phrases that are related to the keys in a natural way. The clues are all there in the "code". Did you notice the [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Connie Talbot
>  **Con**(sole)
>  (a)**n**(d)
>  **i**
>  **e**
>  **tal**(lest mountain)
>  (ro)**bot**